# BMW/Mini CAN BUS (K-CAN) - Adding spurs with UNTWISTED pairs

Tags: automotive

I am in the process of upgrading my headlights on my Mini.  I currently have the halogen units, and I'm retrofitting LED units.

One of the differences is that the LED units require connecting to the K-CAN.

I'm aware the standard calls for twisted pair connection, terminated with 120ohm resistors.

According to the BMW documentation, the body CAN (K-CAN) operates at 100 kbps.

Some people who have done this mod, have done so without running twisted pairs, simply reusing the existing wiring.

**Question number 1** is how stable would this connection be if run on UNTWISTED pairs?  I would rather run a twisted pair, but the work involved in insulating and waterproofing it, and getting it through the bulkhead and properly routed is massive.  Reusing the existing wires, although not to standard, would be much easier, if the connection would be reliable enough.

**Question number 2** regards the way in which I connect into the existing canbus, regardless of twisted or untwisted pairs.

At the moment, the CAN BUS wiring runs straight from the BDC to the terminating resistor, R3, in the rear of the vehicle.  Then connected to R3 are the Longitudinal Torque Distribution and the Reversing Camera.

Had the headlights be factory fitted, then according to the wiring diagram, the CAN BUS wiring would split at location X1325*5V and X1325*6V, and head to 1 headlight, with a further splice at X1325*3V and X1325*4V heading to the other headlight.  So I know a parallel connection is viable.

Additionally, I'm adding a pair of spot lights that also need to connect to the same CAN BUS.

What is the best way to add THREE wires to each of the CAN BUS lines?

I do have a spare terminating resistor which has 10 pairs of connection points, but I'm worried this would skew the impedance on the BUS.

[image: K-CAN3 connection at BDC]
[image: K-CAN3 topology WITH LED headlights]

**EDIT** Adding all the CAN BUS info I have

[image: CAN BUS details]
[image: CAN BUS details]
[image: CAN BUS details]
[image: CAN BUS details]
[image: CAN BUS details]
[image: CAN BUS details]
[image: CAN BUS details]
[image: Location A258 *3B]
[image: Location X1325 *5V/*6V]
[image: Location X1325 *3V/*4V]
[image: Location E86*1B]
[image: Location E5*1B]

Comment: Twisted or untwisted, how stable can't be answered as the specs for the bus are not known, like how long stubs are allowed and what is the minimum distance between stubs without disturbing the signal integrity on the bus, unless you follow the original wiring specs. And you can't add more termination resistors to an already properly terminated bus. I guess bus signals could be measured before and after modding, but the problem is how to know how much signal degradation is acceptable.

Comment: @Justme - thank you.  I've added all the info I have regarding the CAN BUS.